# returning a modified array after comparing in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [10,20,7]
arr2=[]
```

On the first array I am performing a division calculation similar to this:

```
 arr1.each do |i|
    res = i.to_f/2.0
   arr2.push(res.round)
 end
```

This will return `arr2 =` [5,10,4]

From the output array again I want to compare with the first array i.e `[10,20,7]`

If the output array `arr2` contains value from any of the value from `arr1`

I want to replace that value with `value/2.0`

I am able to do a comparison like below:

```
arr2.any?{|x| arr1.include?(x)}
```

But I want to replace that value after comparing. How can I do that?

Comment: The construction of `arr2` can be done in one step: `arr2 = arr1.map { |n| m = (n/2.0).ceil; arr1.include?(m) ? m/2.0 : m }`. If `arr1` is large this can be sped up: `require 'set'; s1 = arr1.to_set; arr2 = arr1.map { |n| m = (n/2.0).ceil; s1.include?(m) ? m/2.0 : m }`

Comment: ...and if `arr1` contains only integers, a little better: `arr2 = arr1.map { |n| m = (n/2.0).ceil; n.even? && arr1.include?(m) ? m/2.0 : m }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `any?` only returns a boolean by evaluating the condition in the block, it doesn't allow you to do any modification to the receiver.

You can do that by using `map` and return a new object, where the values present in `arr2` and in `arr1` are divided by 2.0:

```
arr2.map do |x|
  match = arr1.find { |y| x == y }
  match ? match / 2.0 : x
end
# [5, 5.0, 4]
```

`find` allows you to look for elements in the receiver that match the condition in the block and return the first of them if exists, otherwise nil.